# Explanation for my polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relation

I have to say that my code is working fine but I don't understand why ... I want to add some custom fields for different "modules".

for exemple I have 3 tables : Cameras, Servers and custom_fields.

Camera & Server model :

```
public function custom_fields()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Camera', 'item', 'description_fields', '', 'name')
        ->withPivot('name', 'value')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

The table for this relation :

```
Schema::create('description_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('item_type');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('value');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I can add some elements via this line in the controller :

```
$camera->custom_fields()->attach($request->custom_field);
```

My question is about the model, why I have write :

**morphToMany('App\Models\Camera', 'item', 'description_fields', '', 'name')**

I don't understand why I have to specify the 2 last parameters: '', 'name' (change 'name' by 'value' and it's working, but if I delete '','name' it doesn't work).

I have read the doc for the params but I still don't understand (I'm not a profesional developper but I learn by myself). If anyone can take 5 minutes to explain me, it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Laravel's source code for the morphToMany method:

```
/**
 * Define a polymorphic many-to-many relationship.
 *
 * @param  string  $related
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $table
 * @param  string  $foreignKey
 * @param  string  $relatedKey
 * @param  bool  $inverse
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function morphToMany($related, $name, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $inverse = false)
{
    $caller = $this->guessBelongsToManyRelation();

    // First, we will need to determine the foreign key and "other key" for the
    // relationship. Once we have determined the keys we will make the query
    // instances, as well as the relationship instances we need for these.
    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $name.'_id';

    $relatedKey = $relatedKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

    // Now we're ready to create a new query builder for this related model and
    // the relationship instances for this relation. This relations will set
    // appropriate query constraints then entirely manages the hydrations.
    $table = $table ?: Str::plural($name);

    return new MorphToMany(
        $instance->newQuery(), $this, $name, $table,
        $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $caller, $inverse
    );
}
```

You are setting `$foreignKey` to '' and `$relatedKey` to 'name'. Look specifically at this part:

```
$relatedKey = $relatedKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();
```

Basically this says if you give me a `$relatedKey` use it else get it from the model instance.

If you go to Model.php to see the source code of the getForeignKey method, you will see this results in a concatenation of the class name + '_' + the default primary key ('id'). So this results in 'camera_id'.

```
/**
 * Get the default foreign key name for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getForeignKey()
{
    return Str::snake(class_basename($this)).'_'.$this->primaryKey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It's working only when I add some data but when I want to get the custom fields from the camera it's doesn't work. I think I my relation is not correct but thanks, I will try to get it !

Comment: I had rewrite my relation by this one :

`return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Server', 'item', 'description_fields', '', 'item_id')->withPivot('name', 'value')->withTimestamps();`

It working fine now but I have to use `{{ $custom_field->pivot->name }}` in blade. It's okay I get it !